# Can't get Ctags working

Tags: ctags, plugin-tagbar

I have a fairly small Javascript project, and when I run `ctags -R` it seems to generate at least some tags. I get a tags file (no extension?) in the root folder, and when I run `wc -l tags` it says `8214 tags`.

However, Ctrl+] never finds any tags, even ones in the same file. Right now, I'm using the supergf plugin for similar functionality but I'm also using Tagbar and most of the functions are showing up empty or not at all. 
(e.g. `void function(?,?,?,?)`)

What am I doing wrong? I also have tern-js installed.

Thanks

Comment: Do you see an error message when you type `Ctrl-]`? Vim will report an error if it can't find a tags file or can't find a tag in the tags file.

Comment: Yeah, it just says "tag not found", no matter what tag I'm searching for.

Comment: OK, then try the command `:echo tagfiles()` and see if the file names it reports include the one you built. If the names are relative, execute `:pwd` to be sure the current working directory is what you think it is.

Comment: You might also try searching for a tag from the command line using the `:tag` command. I'm wondering if your `iskeyword` setting conflicts with the ctags program's idea of what a word is, which would interfere with the ability of `Ctrl-]` to grab the right tag.

Comment: When you write *"I also have tern-js installed."*, is it only the node module or the node module *and* [tern_for_vim](https://github.com/marijnh/tern_for_vim)? That plugin provides — among other features — a "jump to definition" command (`:TernDef`) that is a lot smarter than `:tag` so… with that plugin installed you don't really need ctags to navigate your JavaScript project. Anyway, do you get anything when doing `:echo taglist(".")`?

Comment: hmm ok so ctags seems to work when I do `Ctrl+]` over a reference to an external js library I'm using, just not for my own code. `:TernDef` isn't working for the functions I'm trying to find either. Maybe I'm using it wrong? `:TernRefs` works.

Answer (score 1):

You should check your current directory to see if its the same as your **tags** file

```
:pwd
```

If not just

```
:cd /to/dir/which/contains/yourtagfile
```

and try again using tags.

Please check [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11975316/vim-ctags-tag-not-found) for ways to set searching directories for tag files

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try the [taglist](http://vim-taglist.sourceforge.net/) plugin. It works perfectly for me.

Comment: Somehow, it's even worse...it doesn't find any of my functions at all.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried storing the `tags` file in the top-level directory of your project and adding this line to your `.vimrc`?

```
set tags=tags
```

Also be sure to start (g)vim in that top-level directory.  `CTRL+N` and `CTRL+P` should work.